# Take copy of RAM

Tags: backup, livecd, ram

How trivial is it to take a copy of the current state of a Live Linux Distro's RAM storage?

I have had situations where it might be useful to debug what caused a problem with the OS, and if I had happened to take a 'snapshot' earlier, thought this would be useful data.

Comment: Did you want to take copy of RAM because of the frozen live CD session as you had pasted in your other question?

Comment: Correct. [Other question (if I am correct about which one you are referring to)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125718/regain-access-to-seemingly-frozen-live-cd-session) is part 1 of the problem, but thought I would start addressing part 2 should part 1 be solvable.

Answer (score 0):

In a virtual environment this can be done by snapshotting that vm.

In all environments `kdump` and the `kexec` tools might help you here.

It depends on the distribution what can or can not be done. So check your specific man pages and vendor docs.

Comment: Thanks Nils. Interestingly enough, I had actually decided to move to a VM environment to prevent the tie'ng up of hardware that OS problems cause too regularly for my liking. I will revisit this answer when I have (hopefully) solved [issue 1](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125718/regain-access-to-seemingly-frozen-live-cd-session) and tried the two tools you specify. P.S Not sure if you wanted to fix the e __n__ vironments and orcan typos above.